Как поставить кавычки при цитировании (зачитывании текста) с использованием авторского текста?
Если персонаж цитирует текст, то как надо ставить кавычки? Пример:

— Читать сегодня будешь или нет?
— «Употреблять два раза в день, — прочитал Владимир, недоуменно оглядев всех. — Рекомендуется
проконсультироваться с лечащим врачом».


— Читать сегодня будешь или нет?
— «Употреблять два раза в день», — прочитал Владимир, недоуменно оглядев всех. — «Рекомендуется
проконсультироваться с лечащим врачом».

Какой из вариантов правильный? Я знаю, что при разрыве прямой речи словами автора кавычки ставятся только в начале и конце прямой речи. Но какое правило применятся в обычной прямой речи при цитировании?

Зачем разрывать цитату, если это цитата?

@Буратино ну, это не совсем цитата, если быть точным. Персонаж как бы читает текст. Это может выглядеть по-разному. Например: "Прочитал Владимир, недоуменно оглядев всех" (я даже добавлю это в вопрос).

XD : https://orfoschool.ru/page_81830_copy39/

@Буратино ахахахаах. это же мой вопрос двухлетней давности (уже и позабыл) :D Но ведь по итогу к единому мнению никто так и не пришел.

Это не важно, главное, вы успешно прошли цифровизацию.) Думаю, раз никто не пришёл, вы сами должны определить, необходимость кавычек. В данном тексте я не думаю, что они вообще нужны, потому что смысловая нагрузка от этого не сильно страдает. Я бы цитату оформил как: - Употреблять два раза в день... - прочила Владимир, - ... рекомендуется проконсультироваться с леч. врачом. То есть многоточием бы просто разорвал, тогда было понятно что это что-то одного рода.

@Буратино спасибо, будем думать. Надеюсь, в 2026 году не появится нового вопроса от меня по этой теме))

Кто знает...) Меня просто больше смущает сам разрыв фразы, а не наличие-отсутствие кавычек.

Ссылка на ответ Грамоты  https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/309779

@Sharon спасибо!

Кстати, там написано "в этом случае", так что не факт, что всегда. Там два глагола говорения (зачитал,  продолжил).

Правильно:
— Читать сегодня будешь или нет?
— «Употреблять два раза в день, — прочитал Владимир, недоуменно оглядев всех. — Рекомендуется проконсультироваться с лечащим врачом».
Пояснение
Смотрим ответ Справочной службы:
№ 310076
 Скажите, пожалуйста, допустима ли такая пунктуация в 
 диалоговом предложении? — "Завтра в полдень у Новореченской 
 вас будет ждать... — Егор на секунду умолк и поднял на меня 
 глаза. — ...Филипп". (Кавычки показывают, что персонаж 
 читает с бумажки, многоточия — что реплика разорвана на 2 
 части авторскими словами.)

 ОТВЕТ
 Достаточно одного многоточия. После слов автора можно 
 поставить **запятую,** так как прямая речь представляет 
 собой одну фразу, разделенную паузой, действием говорящего: 
 «Завтра в полдень у Новореченской вас будет ждать... — Егор 
 на секунду умолк и поднял на меня глаза, — Филипп».

Для нашего случая  важно указание на кавычки, а остальное оформляем по обычным правилам.

Спасибо за ответ.

Если персонаж цитирует текст, то как надо ставить кавычки?
Я бы оформил так:

— Читать сегодня будешь или нет?
— «Употреблять два раза в день», — прочитал Владимир, недоуменно
оглядев всех. — «Рекомендуется проконсультироваться с лечащим врачом».

Примеры из худ. литературы

— «Не волнуйся, скоро буду. Всегда твой», — прочитала она вслух. —
Наверное, опять решил кому-нибудь помочь. Татьяна Тронина.


«Милая моя, дорогая, мучение мое, тоска моя», — прочитала она, держа
письмо в обеих руках и давая им обеим упиваться прикосновением к этим
милым, горячим строкам. А. П. Чехов.


Обломов взглянул на подпись. — «Радищев», — прочитал он. — Э! И. А. Гончаров.


— «Усов», — прочитал он, подумал и стал осторожно нагревать бумажку на
спичке, разбирая: — «быв. студ. сдан в солд. учит. Максим Горький.


Спасибо и за ваш ответ и эти примеры.
